# Is removing dropouts before deploying with tensorflow/keras advisable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a trained keras model that i plan to serve with tensorflow-serving, it uses dropout layers several times in its architecture but i read somewhere a long time ago that dropout layers aren't frozen and actually makes the model output different results from "in-console results" if still included in the served model... This model is 1 in a list of models which i usually load like so:

```
from keras.models import load_model
modelList = []
for filee in os.listdir("/kaggle/input/models/"):
    tempMod = load_model("/kaggle/input/models/" + str(filee) )
    tempMod.trainable = False
    modelList.append(tempMod)
    print("/kaggle/input/models/" + str(filee) )
print(modelList)
```

1. I am not sure about this information, do i really need to manually remove the dropout layers before serving?
2. If yes, how exactly do i go about removing the said layers, non-destructively from my trained model.
   This is my model summary/architecture:

> ```
> Model: "model_24"
> _________________________________________________________________
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> input_32 (InputLayer)        (None, 128, 157, 1)       0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_103 (Conv2D)          (None, 126, 154, 32)      416       
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_87 (MaxPooling (None, 63, 77, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_87 (Dropout)         (None, 63, 77, 32)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_104 (Conv2D)          (None, 61, 75, 64)        18496     
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_88 (MaxPooling (None, 20, 25, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_88 (Dropout)         (None, 20, 25, 64)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_105 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 23, 512)       295424    
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_89 (MaxPooling (None, 6, 7, 512)         0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_89 (Dropout)         (None, 6, 7, 512)         0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> conv2d_106 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 5, 1024)        4719616   
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_90 (MaxPooling (None, 2, 2, 1024)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_90 (Dropout)         (None, 2, 2, 1024)        0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> flatten_24 (Flatten)         (None, 4096)              0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_47 (Dense)             (None, 128)               524416    
> _________________________________________________________________
> dropout_92 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_48 (Dense)             (None, 50)                6450      
> =================================================================
> Total params: 11,129,636
> Trainable params: 5,564,818
> Non-trainable params: 5,564,818
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

Comment: "read somewhere a long time ago" is not really a good base for a question, there is nothing you need to do regarding Dropout, it is implemented correctly in Keras. Have you even tested that the model actually works? A simple test would tell you that whatever you read some time ago is completely incorrect

Comment: it works perfectly, "in-console" but i needed to be sure it'll work the same when served, because of this post: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/602

Comment: this is a quote from that same post "When you use predict in non-serving situation, the dropout layer is automatically ignored, which is, all neurons are used. BUT when you export your model to servable and serve it with tensorflow_model_server，it is not a regular predicting operation. It's more like a frozen serial of ops that the tensor follows. Thus if the dropout layer is "frozen" in your servable, it will randomly drop half of your neurons and cause problem. (My English is poor so if you don't understand please feel free to ask!)"

Comment: I would completely ignore that issue, there is no enough detail to see what was wrong (no code either), and she probably just exported the model the wrong way (without setting the learning phase), did you notice that she was basically talking alone about the issue? In the end if the model is correctly exported Dropout should work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Yes this is indeed true. You should not be using Dropout layers during inference. Dropout is a sort of regularizer which loosely speaking makes the task harder for a neural net to learn thus providing better generalization error.

Fortunately when using Keras if you choose model.predict() dropout layers by default are not used.

For tensorflow serving you can just remove the dropout layer from you model definition and load as you are currently loading. Since dropout layer has no weight associated with it everything will work

Comment: No, this answer is completely incorrect, there is literally nothing you need to do regarding Dropout about inference, Keras already handles this correctly, do not try to mess with it

Comment: @sagarwal thank you, but my second question is, how do i "remove the said dropout layers" from my model definition before loading

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy do you mean to suggest i try serving the model the way it is, with the dropouts?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy why do you feel my answer is completely wrong. Infact I have written that when using model.predict() Keras will not use dropout layers

Comment: @TochiBedford for tensorflow serving use keras.set_learning_phase(0) before exporting the model.

Comment: @sagarwal Because what you are saying is not true and it can confuse people, you do not need to do anything special for dropout layers to work, the only exception is to set the learning phase when exporting the model. In the end the link that started this question was just a misunderstanding that needs to be clarified

Comment: @sagarwal For example your comment that you should not be using Dropout layers during inference triggers the question of how to remove the layers, which will break the model if done, and it is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you just acknowledged that learning phase needs to be changed when exporting the the model. Yes if you are not moving out of keras than you don't need to do anything and this is what I have already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @sagarwal Switching the learning phase is not the same as removing the Dropout layers

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy indeed my comment is correct. Dropout should not be enabled when doing inference. Keras is just being nice by automatically fixing that in predict mode.

Comment: @sagarwal Dropout has multiple working modes, what would "not be enabled" mean?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy what do you mean by break the model ?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy pardon my ignorance. I am only aware of two modes. One where it randomly drops a percentage of activations from previous layers and other where it is a no-op. By not enabled I mean it being a no-op. Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: @sagarwal keras.set_learning_phase will be removed in Oct 2020
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_learning_phase?version=nightly